# Ubuntu 16.04.01 - Kernel 4.4.0-31 does not load after Nvidia 367.35 installation

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, kernel

'dpkg --get-selections | grep -i linux-image' outputs the following:

```
linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic            install
linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic            install
linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic            install
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic      install
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic      install
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic      install
linux-image-generic                     install
```

After I installed Nvidia driver 367.35 w/ the executable installer from Nvidia website, kernel version 4.4.0-31-generic will not boot. In order to boot into Ubuntu I need to reboot (Ctrl+Alt+Del) & select Adv. options>4.4.0-21-generic.

I tried using these settings in '/etc/default/grub':

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 (purposefully added '#')
GRUB_TIMEOUT=8
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

& then running these commands:

```
sudo grub-set-default 'gnulinux-4.4.0-21-generic-advanced-adca821f-3b5f-45ef-a63e-69abf07b566c'
sudo update-grub
```

I could use some help fixing this problem. I am willing to gather any extra information if it'll help determine a solution. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
None of the kernels boot up anymore ('Recovery' loads). After selection of kernel to boot, all I'll see is a black screen. Not hearing the usual boot up sounds..

It might be worth mentioning I blacklisted nouveau w/ '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf'. I receive an error message about a bad line in '/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau-kms.conf' being ignored.

I have a graphics add-in card, and dual monitors connected via dms-59 pin -> VGA adapter.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: How would one do that if they don't have UEFI? @Pilot6

Comment: There is no such a problem without UEFI.  Do you have UEFI? Also you will have this problem if you installed the driver from a .run file.

Comment: Oh, well, that is how I installed - using 'NVIDIA...run' downloaded from their official site. So, is there a workaround or is the best option to reinstall using 'apt-get install' & install from PPA?

Comment: That is a wrong way. You need to install it again after each kernel upgrade. You should install drivers from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I can not boot any of the kernels, except for Recovery. I'll edit & add details soon..

Comment: If I can somehow backup files from Ubuntu w/ a graphical interface, then my plan at this point is to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: You do not need to reinstall. You can install drivers from recovery.

Comment: Please install drivers via official Canonical ppa at https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa I have had no issues installing latest drivers via this method. The .run method is not recommended for Ubuntu as per Canonical norms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed these issues, at the cost of my data. Decided to do a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04.1. I didn't decided that I did not have important data.

This solution may have solved my issues, BUT it was at the cost of the data housed within. I don't suggest others jump to this solution for the reasons I did. [Arup Roy Chowdhury](https://askubuntu.com/users/43920/arup-roy-chowdhury) suggested a better solution:

> Please install drivers via official Canonical ppa at
>   [launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) I have had no
>   issues installing latest drivers via this method. The .run method is
>   not recommended for Ubuntu as per Canonical norms.  – [Arup Roy Chowdhury](https://askubuntu.com/users/43920/arup-roy-chowdhury)